# php malware file-names

Tags: malware, php

The following is a list malware php file-names that I found on my server some time ago, looking at the source these were clearly to allow a hacker to take full control of my server.  I'm posting these names because I was unable to find any mention of them on the internet in a recent google search. I'd like to make people aware that these are dangerous files and every system administrator should check that these files do not exist on their systems and that these files do not crop up in their access logs.  Apologies if I'm just repeating a well known story.

- cache-15.php
- memcache-9a.php
- memcache-15.php
- memcache-cb3.php,
- reverse-cb3.php
- sort-15f.php
- sql-9a.php
- sql-cb.php
- utf8-9a.php
- utf8-15f.php

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! I suggest you re-write your post to our Question-and-Answer format. The question would be "are these files malware". The answer would be "Yes, because... " and some proof that they're malware. Not anecdotal evidence, but an analysis or findings from a reliable security company. You may want to precede your question with "This will be a self-answered question", because new users can't self-answer for 15 minutes after posting their question. Good luck!

Comment: [Go to pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com/) and enter the code to each file, and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the name of the files that you have mentioned can be different as anyone can change the name to whatever they like. It can be wp-blog.php, administrator1.php, wp-cron-2.php, etc. Server Administrators should look inside the file and not the filename. Besides I think it is not a good idea to post like this. You should ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what people name a file. You could name it `DrWhoEncryption.php`, or `DalekBuffaloAttack.php`, and they could do something completely opposite of what they say they do.

It isn't the name, but the contents you need to worry about. If you post the contents of some of these files, we can probably discover what exactly is going on. However, you appear to know already that these files are dangerous. Did you look at the code?

I am in full agreement with Err0rr. You didn't ask a question. Why not pastebin the file contents to let us know what they are, and ask us what's going on?